# How to set color in HTML5 "please wait" spinner?

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to use the HTML5 capability to have a "please wait" spinner.  An example of this can be found at the article [Loading spinner animation using CSS and WebKit](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2577-loading-spinner-animation-using-css-and-webkit), illustrated through this sub-page [(no title, but a working example of the prior link)](http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/462-png_spinner.html).

I've no trouble in copying the code (from a different link than the one I gave here) and making it run in my own web page.  My difficulty is in making it the correct color.  For example, in the example I used the dial segments are all colored red.  I see no color setter, no "color", "background" or "background-color" in the CSS for the spinner or set explicitly in the DIV.  Or at least no setting of these that actually changes the color of the segment.

Can someone give me a clue?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can merely change the background color before the mask image and the spinner color will change. The second link you posted is using a mask image, not an actual colored image. The mask soins around a colored div, that's all. Change the background color of the div, and the spinner color changes.

```
p#spinner {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f00;  /* <----- this controls spinner color -------- */
  /* mask image removed from this post only due to space */
}
```

for the "please wait" spinner, it's a matter of changing the background color of the spinner divs and the color for the label:

```
div.labeled div.spinner div { background: #090; } 
div.labeled { color: #090; }
```

as seen here: [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/umowis/6/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The second link that you gave is indeed an image, so you'll have to manually change the color if you wish to do it that way. However, the article that you linked to actually gave a different method. If you read it carefully, you'll notice that the first thing it speaks about is simply rotating an image via CSS (which is why you're confused). It then goes to show how to create the spinner itself using simple HTML and CSS3. [Here's a link to a working demo of the spinner, without using images.](http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/463-single_spinner.html)

In the demo, the entire spinner is contained in a `div` called `spinner`, and the individual bars are `divs` themselves. There is a CSS background style on `div.spinner div`, and you can modify the color via that style.

Comment: Adding the change to div.spinner div isn't working for me.  Suppose I want the color to be #00cc00.  What follows is the code I swiped from this site: [link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/461-spinner.html) ``

Answer (score 0):

(This editor is giving me problems today...)
The div.spinner div answer doesn't get me  there.

Here is the original link, http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/461-spinner.html.  In it I'm interested in the named "Please Wait" spinner.  It is red.  I can easily change the text color, but the spinning segments remain frustratingly red.

To save you the trouble, I'm copying the contents, including a color of #00cc00, into this comment.  Note that the green color doesn't appear anywhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Spinner</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        background: #e5e5e5;
        text-align: center;
      }

    /* start basic spinner styles*/

    div.spinner {
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    div.spinner div {
      width: 12%;
      height: 26%;
      background: #000;
      position: absolute;
      left: 44.5%;
      top: 37%;
      opacity: 0;
      color: #00cc00;
      -webkit-animation: fade 1s linear infinite;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    div.spinner div.bar1 {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;}
    div.spinner div.bar2 {-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9167s;}
    div.spinner div.bar3 {-webkit-transform:rotate(60deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.833s;}
    div.spinner div.bar4 {-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.75s;}
    div.spinner div.bar5 {-webkit-transform:rotate(120deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.667s;}
    div.spinner div.bar6 {-webkit-transform:rotate(150deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5833s;}
    div.spinner div.bar7 {-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;}
    div.spinner div.bar8 {-webkit-transform:rotate(210deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.41667s;}
    div.spinner div.bar9 {-webkit-transform:rotate(240deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.333s;}
    div.spinner div.bar10 {-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.25s;}
    div.spinner div.bar11 {-webkit-transform:rotate(300deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1667s;}
    div.spinner div.bar12 {-webkit-transform:rotate(330deg) translate(0, -142%); -webkit-animation-delay: -0.0833s;}

     @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: 1;}
      to {opacity: 0.25;}
    }

    /* end basic spinner styles*/

    div.container {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1.5em 1.5em 1.25em;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
      -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
      margin: 1em;
    }

    div.container.grey {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
    div.container.grey.blue {background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0a2744), color-stop(1, #064483));}

    div.container div.spinner {
      width: 28px;
      height: 28px;
    }

    div.container.grey div.spinner {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
    }

    div.container div.spinner div {background: #fff;}

    div.labeled {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.5em;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #c00;
      line-height: 25px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(1, #ccc));
    }

    div.labeled div.spinner {
      float: left;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      margin-right: 0.5em;
    }

    div.labeled div.spinner div {background: #c00;}

    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
    <div class="bar7"></div>
    <div class="bar8"></div>
    <div class="bar9"></div>
    <div class="bar10"></div>
    <div class="bar11"></div>
    <div class="bar12"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="spinner" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
    <div class="bar7"></div>
    <div class="bar8"></div>
    <div class="bar9"></div>
    <div class="bar10"></div>
    <div class="bar11"></div>
    <div class="bar12"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="spinner" style="width: 34px; height: 34px">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
    <div class="bar7"></div>
    <div class="bar8"></div>
    <div class="bar9"></div>
    <div class="bar10"></div>
    <div class="bar11"></div>
    <div class="bar12"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="spinner" style="width: 19px; height: 19px">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
    <div class="bar7"></div>
    <div class="bar8"></div>
    <div class="bar9"></div>
    <div class="bar10"></div>
    <div class="bar11"></div>
    <div class="bar12"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="labeled">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
      <div class="bar4"></div>
      <div class="bar5"></div>
      <div class="bar6"></div>
      <div class="bar7"></div>
      <div class="bar8"></div>
      <div class="bar9"></div>
      <div class="bar10"></div>
      <div class="bar11"></div>
      <div class="bar12"></div>
    </div>
    Please waitâ€¦
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
      <div class="bar4"></div>
      <div class="bar5"></div>
      <div class="bar6"></div>
      <div class="bar7"></div>
      <div class="bar8"></div>
      <div class="bar9"></div>
      <div class="bar10"></div>
      <div class="bar11"></div>
      <div class="bar12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container grey">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
      <div class="bar4"></div>
      <div class="bar5"></div>
      <div class="bar6"></div>
      <div class="bar7"></div>
      <div class="bar8"></div>
      <div class="bar9"></div>
      <div class="bar10"></div>
      <div class="bar11"></div>
      <div class="bar12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container grey blue">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
      <div class="bar4"></div>
      <div class="bar5"></div>
      <div class="bar6"></div>
      <div class="bar7"></div>
      <div class="bar8"></div>
      <div class="bar9"></div>
      <div class="bar10"></div>
      <div class="bar11"></div>
      <div class="bar12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Oh, yes... this is WebKit code, and I haven't made Mozilla display it properly.  Use Chrome.

Comment: I figured the stupid thing now.  The final div.labeled div.spinner div is what controls everything. It overwrites my color: #00cc00.

Comment: These two lines controlled the labeled spinner color and the text color.... `div.labeled div.spinner div { background: #090; } div.labeled { color: #090; }`